# Rename file permission

Tags: php, zip, chmod

I am trying to copy over some files pulled out from a zip folder, from out of the directory. I modified the code from this page

[Extract Directory Inside Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859396/extract-directory-inside-zip)

for the most part it works, but when it is attempting the rename the directory files it pulls I get the following error

```
Warning: rename(.,Manga/Naruto/Hell/.) [function.rename]: Permission denied in C:\public_html\mangaUpload.php on line 124

Warning: rename(..,Manga/Naruto/Hell/..) [function.rename]: Permission denied in C:\public_html\mangaUpload.php on line 124
```

despite the fact I have chomed all the folders being used, here is the code

```
if(!file_exists("Manga"))
    {
      mkdir("Manga",0777);
      chmod("Manga",0777);
    }

    if(!file_exists("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']))
    {
      mkdir("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName'],0777);
      chmod("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName'],0777);
    }
    if(!file_exists("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']))
    {
      mkdir("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName'],0777);
      chmod("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName'],0777);
    }

        $pathname = "Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']."/";
        $chapterZip = new ZipArchive();


        if ($chapterZip->open($_FILES['chapterUpload']['tmp_name']) === true) { 

            for($i = 0; $i < $chapterZip->numFiles; $i++) {



      $chapterZip->extractTo($pathname, array($chapterZip->getNameIndex($i))); 
        chmod($pathname.$chapterZip->getNameIndex($i),0777);

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($pathname.$chapterZip->getNameIndex($i));

            $imageLocation= "INSERT INTO imageLocation (imageLocation,imageWidth,imageHeight,chapterID) VALUES  ('"."Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']."/".$chapterZip->getNameIndex($i).
            "',".$width.",".$height.",".$chapterID.")";
            getQuery($imageLocation,$l);                  
        }

       $chapterZip->close();
           $directories = glob($pathname.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

       if ($directories !== FALSE) {

      foreach($directories as $directory) {

        $dir_handle = opendir($directory);
        while(($filename = readdir($dir_handle)) !== FALSE) {

          // Move all subdirectory contents to "Chapter Folder"
          if (rename($filename, $pathname.basename($filename)) === FALSE) {
           $errmsg0.= "Error moving file ($filename) \n";
                }
                else {
                $errmsg0.="You have successfully uploaded a manga chapter";
                }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL it's not a permission problem :)
a workaround:

```
while(($filename = readdir($dir_handle)) !== FALSE) {
  if ($filename[0] == ".") continue;
```

consider to use modern [glob()](http://php.net/glob) instead of ancient opendir.

Comment: The DirectoryIterator class is probabaly more of a replacement.. http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Answer (score 1):

Exclude `.` and `..` from the `rename` loop as they are aliases that refer to current folder and parent folder respectively (remember why you do `cd ..` to go to parent folder):

```
   while(($filename = readdir($dir_handle)) !== FALSE) {
      if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') {
         // Move all subdirectory contents to "Chapter Folder"
         if (rename($filename, $pathname.basename($filename)) === FALSE) {
           $errmsg0.= "Error moving file ($filename) \n";
            }
            else {
            $errmsg0.="You have successfully uploaded a manga chapter";
            }
         }
      }
    }
```